# How to get those tr of a table containing a text_field with a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a table with several rows in which each td has a field, but I need to search for those tr containing the value "Egress" in a text_field. The value "Egress" is entered by the user and is not specified in the code.

I am trying something like this in coffeescript:

```
$('.payroll_novelties tr:has(.types[value="Egress"])').each ->

  cantidad = $(this).find("td:eq(4) input")
  valor = $(this).find("td:eq(5) input").val()
```

The code works for me but only if the value "egress" is in the code, but it does not work if it is typed by the user. How can I fix it?

Comment: First off all, provide live working example to codepen or jsfiddle to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution as follows:

```
$('.payroll_novelties tr').each ->

  if $(this).find("td:eq(3) input").val() == "Egress"
```